# Loading a TrueType font file in Tkinter without installing it in fonts folder

Tags: python, tkinter, truetype

How do I load a TrueType font file in Tkinter without installing it in the font directories and beside the running script, like for example in Windows/Linux?

I'm trying to create a script with the fonts not need to be installed separately and already included in my main package.

Comment: Render it as a vector image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot dynamically load fonts with tkinter.

Comment: while this is a true and correct answer, it would benefit greatly from suggesting alternative ways to solve the problem.